# Enforce readonly array parameter for using the values of one key as string union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

I was wondering whether it is possible to enforce a caller to provide a readonly array as function parameter. Specifically, I want to pass an array of objects to a function and its second parameter is the value of one of the keys of the objects (as a string union). For that to work with TypeScript, it needs to be readonly, because TypeScript "loses" the string literals by widening them to `string`s when using the mutable array.

[Here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIGEAWB7AlgYzgXlgb2LIbOihtAJIAmAXLAM6gBOqAdgOYA0BRANgIYAjaD1oNm7YAF8QAMwCuLdKFTIW9YdCVI0mADwAVbWTqxoAD1DQWlEwCVofSqp7gAgo0Z9wuo5gB8fgAU3IQkOtB0tIakmHRcRLCsqMp8PL4UNLDR4SbmltZ2Dk4sLu6e3ul+sAD8Wel0ANoscgC2QowAug0ARGFkVN0dsLQs0ABu0IzAAJS06bAAPrDNPDx4IbCM0KByjGp9sQB0MqyUgQfYVReHF1SwWA+JLMmoqelU0zW1KzxSIAD0-1gTgiLAA5KBYAB3ZCMADWHHoKDkPEosBkfFQvzoGi0MWgwQSDVwxHxVFo3VQlAAjN1EfwhCJYN0GcJYLTYJJESTbplKZQAEx02CspkswRsoWcjrxIjdKGMVRsAC0VOVqmVkF2kGQOO6MxA6FUDFJOVcdHgxshOGJpv6fKptPpErFovZ3U53LtmHJzKpQudjIpbqlkiGfBMRpYDABQJh8LowBxPE0oHS53xdHNlujoER-Np02AgOhsLhcXRmJ4JlUsC1jB1OKTuLT+IzZotVvzCqVqso6pYmu1uug3SLydT6dtvIpjuFouDLvd0u7ivYfYHQ4bI7HIGAUZNFzoADlkGmrfcNtOyQ6afOXYvGcuuXhvRlZ4L70HmSGPWHY8CyCghCpbws2KZ4uE7bGKe565vmc5FiWIJ0OCkLxgiSLICiaIYli4GTm2R6wTmDCrr2aoavWjajkWwBAA)

..and here is an example:

We have a `Choice` and a function to select one from an array:

```
type Choice = {
    choiceId: string,
    label: string
}

const choices: Choice[] = [{ choiceId: "choiceId1", label: "label 1" }]

function selectChoice<TChoices extends ReadonlyArray<Choice>>(
    choices: TChoices,
    initialChoiceId: TChoices[number]["choiceId"]
): Choice | null {
    return choices.find(choice => choice.choiceId === initialChoiceId) ?? null
}

// call the function and get auto-complete/type-safe usage for the ID
selectChoice(choices, "choiceId1")
```

For this to work, the `choices` input *must* be a readonly array (`TChoices extends ReadonlyArray<Choice>`). A normal array is not enough.

Here are different ways to call the function:

```
// Example 1: This should fail (wrong ID), but doesn't, because the choices are not readonly.
selectChoice(
    [{ choiceId: "id1", label: "label 1" }, { choiceId: "id2", label: "label 2" }],
    "wrong-id-on-purpose"
)

// If we instead define the array `as const`, it works.
const choicesAsConst =
    [{ choiceId: "id1", label: "label 1" }, { choiceId: "id2", label: "label 2" }] as const

// Example 2: works
selectChoice(choicesAsConst, "id1")
// Example 3: works, fails on purpose
selectChoice(choicesAsConst, "wrong-id-on-purpose")
```

Can you somehow force the caller to provide a readonly array? Otherwise it would be easy to not recognize that you're not using the function in a type-safe manner (see "Example 1" above). Does one maybe need to have a custom type guard to check this?

Or maybe there is a better way alltogether? e.g. I know this works when providing an object instead of an array of objects, but in the described use case, an array makes more sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the passed array to be `readonly` by checking if it has a non-`readonly` property like `push`.

```
function selectChoice<TChoices extends readonly Choice[]>(
    choices: TChoices,
    initialChoiceId: TChoices extends { push: any } 
      ? never 
      : TChoices[number]["choiceId"]
): Choice | null {
    return choices.find(choice => choice.choiceId === initialChoiceId) ?? null
}
```

This following example still fails even though TypeScript could infer that this is correct:

```
selectChoice([{ choiceId: "id1", label: "label 1" }], "id1") 
// Error: this array isn't readonly
```

Also note that checking if the array is `readonly` is not enough since normal arrays can also be `readonly`.

```
selectChoice(choicesAsConst as readonly Choice[], "bla") 
// this should not work
```

---

If you also want the example from above to succeed, you will have to tell TypeScript that the `choidId` field needs to be narrowed to a `string` literal type.

```
type Choice<C> = {
    choiceId: C,
    label: string
}

function selectChoice<TChoices extends readonly Choice<C>[], C extends string>(
    choices: TChoices,
    initialChoiceId: TChoices[number]["choiceId"] extends infer U 
      ? string extends U 
        ? never
        : U
      : never
): Choice<string> | null {
    return choices.find(choice => choice.choiceId === initialChoiceId) ?? null
}
```

And if `TChoices[number]["choiceId"]` turns out to be just a `string` and not a string literal type, we can evaluate `initialChoiceId` to `never`.

```
// works
selectChoice(choicesAsConst, "id1")
// error
selectChoice(choicesAsConst, "wrong-id-on-purpose")

// works
selectChoice([{ choiceId: "id1", label: "label 1" }], "id1")
// error
selectChoice([{ choiceId: "id1", label: "label 1" }], "wrong-id-on-purpose")

// error
selectChoice(choicesNotConst, "id1")
// error
selectChoice(choicesNotConst, "wrong-id-on-purpose")
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIGEAWB7AlgY2gHngPlgLywDews5s6KG0AkgCYBcCANGRQDYCGARtB8wDOoAE6oAdgHNgAXxAAzAK7j0oVMnGxB-aKqRpMWACr6ag2NAAeoaOPrmR0LvQ0dwCaobwBtALosEC2tbey1RCUlcAAp2cioDaEFmE09EtgpYCVQ1Lg5TTAZk-MTvcUUAWz4RX28AIniaBlrfIJs7cwl5aBFYAFVYWIoAfjCxKVaQ837BjJHxaAA3bpmKZl6V5nmlkWAASmZirGExyNgAH1gyjg4SQcdQRRFNBsxBADp5CXool7gCfF%20b1%20DEIBCIWRyeVSDF2sCGc0U11kIAA9CjYC5EuIAOSgWAAd2QIgA1gFBChEfRYPIuKgOMBtBxdKBijEMt5iJRoUxYLVUPQAIy1ALcPgCXmi-iwIWwGQBTnAnl8%20gAJmFsEl4tqmtgatl-kGtXxIg0kgAtPyzRozZBHpBkNpansQOgNMIuQlBABBQTwN14ogcj2NJX8oUi3j8ZjayM3GVykjBgqh1XqzXRnV6mQtLjmV3iYSo9GEkmCBk6PSpH6pb2%20-0BZVC3bANEEonEwQBGl08waWC2kT27TlpmVhLVz0%20v0F0AN42mi30K3iG12h3QWrNkfM1lBxXRsNp2MZ2PS2r6huH5uMndVvfcg%20Co9ik9is8X3nzqSL5erwfrzcQGAfN3V%20QQADlkBZf1CEGe8EkKXlDwjF8JVPeN5STOgUzVFCozQt8s18IsMWQLFcTbEltzHGgJzMSDoJnS8n2bVtMUEHE8RLUktApDgqW7ekbxozA6NeBjp2EOcTW-S1rQHIcNy3IA)

Comment: Thanks! I tried inferring the generic earlier, but `string extends U` was the missing piece.